# Unknown column in 'where clause'. Neste subquery to improve perfomance of 'ORDER BY'

Tags: mysql, nested, subquery

I have an a relationship a little odd but must be so:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) 
 FROM `radcliente` `t`
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_endereco_instalacao` `endereco_instalacao`
      ON (`endereco_instalacao`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_telefone` `telefones`
      ON (`telefones`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_email` `emails`
      ON (`emails`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `radmetodo_cobranca` `metodo_cobranca`
      ON (`metodo_cobranca`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`) AND (metodo_cobranca.arquivo = 'nao')
LEFT OUTER JOIN `radacct` `ultimo_acct`
      ON (`ultimo_acct`.`username`=`t`.`login`) 
     AND (ultimo_acct.radacctid = (
         SELECT `radacctid` FROM
                  (SELECT radacctid
                     FROM `radacct` `fUzDDUDv` 
                    WHERE username = t.login
                  ) AS `fUzDDUDv` ORDER BY `radacctid` DESC LIMIT 1
                                  )
         )
WHERE (ultimo_acct.framedipaddress = '177.23.209.194')
```

Unknown column 't.login' in 'where clause'.

**UPDATE:**

Yes, that would solve a problem. I created this sub query why I'm using the Yii Framework, and the has_one relationships there is no limit, ie if one 'cliente' with millions of 'acct', the framework seeks all 'acct', to take only one this gives some GB of traffic and is very slow. To solve, I used the subquery seeking only the newest id to get the 'cliente' and the last 'acct' and make it work in Active Record, until then everything was fine, but the search was slow estremamente to seek a record took 40 seconds, then I discovered that the problem was in the 'ORDER BY' (radacctid is an index and tables are innodb), hence I did to solve the 'ORDER BY' outside the subquery, then resolvou, the problem that the subquery column the table 'cliente' (t.login) is like there, as I explained above.

I've tried also sort by another field, eg 'acctstarttime', and continued slow, only solved when I did it this way:

```
SELECT `radacctid` FROM
              (SELECT radacctid
                 FROM `radacct` `fUzDDUDv` 
                WHERE username = t.login
              ) AS `fUzDDUDv` ORDER BY `radacctid` DESC LIMIT 1
```

**UPDATE:**

But the problem of INNER JOIN is that if there is no result for 'acct' does not return the 'cliente'.

**UPDATE**

The problem is not where the `t`.`login` but it is not recognized as existing within the subquery that I can not put 'out' if the order is not slow.

**UPDATE**

Read my comments? This is the situation. It really is only on the production server that has inserts and updates all the time.

Comment: I'm sorry for not addressing the question directly: I saw in your statment one thing that we had many problems with while working with ERP database. This concerns WHERE section of your main, topmost SQL statement. You use in your WHERE clause `(ultimo_acct.framedipaddress = '177.23.209.194')` while `ultimo_acct` is a table "left joined" to your basic set in query - this comparison will, as far as I know from my experience, cause your query to treat `ultimo_acct` as it where INNER-JOINED.

Comment: As far as I know mysql might have not recognized `t.login` in your original subquery because it was one level too much nested in relation to top query where `t` table was. Instead of `(ultimo_acct.radacctid = (SELECT radacctid FROM
(SELECT radacctid  FROM radacct fUzDDUDv WHERE username = t.login) AS fUzDDUDv ORDER BY radacctid DESC LIMIT 1)` it's enough to use `(ultimo_acct.radacctid = (SELECT fUzDDUDv.radacctid FROM radacct fUzDDUDv  WHERE fUzDDUDv.username = t.login ORDER BY fUzDDUDv.radacctid DESC LIMIT 1))` and with this modification mysql shouldn't, as far as I know, give error

Comment: Yes, that works, but is too slow 'ORDER BY'.

Comment: So if I understand well, the part `(SELECT fUzDDUDv.radacctid FROM radacct fUzDDUDv WHERE fUzDDUDv.username = t.login ORDER BY fUzDDUDv.radacctid DESC LIMIT 1))` slows down the whole query, you suppose?

Comment: Absolute certainty, but only slows when used with WHERE if you stay only in an ORDER BY 'phpmyadmin' for example, is not slow (0.0007) and only using WHERE without ORDER BY with LIKE (0.0019), and remembering that t.login fUzDDUDv .username are index. I believe that is why the number of the query results are great also seems to be fast, it pauses at "Sending data" using "sort". Other server gives the same thing locally is faster believe because no "queries" to all momendo the Freeradius.

Comment: On my local server is pretty fast from the traditional method only a subquery, but take into account that my production server is much more powerful and is configured to use the my.cnf memory, etc ... the only real difference is that the table acct production server receives update and inserts almost all the time. On another server with the same configuration the only difference that has no "movement" in radacct table, is super fast (0.3809 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one could help you in some way:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) 
FROM 
    `radcliente` `t` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_endereco_instalacao` `endereco_instalacao` 
        ON (`endereco_instalacao`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_telefone` `telefones` 
        ON (`telefones`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_email` `emails` 
        ON (`emails`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `radmetodo_cobranca` `metodo_cobranca` 
        ON (`metodo_cobranca`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`) 
            AND (metodo_cobranca.arquivo = 'nao') 
    INNER JOIN  
    (
     SELECT `ultimo_acct_INNER`.*
     FROM 
        `radacct` AS `ultimo_acct_INNER`
        INNER JOIN 
        (
         SELECT `fUzDDUDv`.`username` AS `maxID_username`, MAX(`radacctid`) AS `maxID_radacctid` 
         FROM  `radacct` `fUzDDUDv` 
         GROUP BY `fUzDDUDv`.`username`
        ) AS `radacct_MAX_ID` 
        ON `ultimo_acct_INNER`.`username`= `radacct_MAX_ID`.`maxID_username`
            AND `ultimo_acct_INNER`.`radacctid` = `radacct_MAX_ID`.`maxID_radacctid`
    ) AS `ultimo_acct`
    ON (`ultimo_acct`.`username`=`t`.`login`)                                  
WHERE 
    (ultimo_acct.framedipaddress = '177.23.209.194')
```

**I replaced section:**

```
(...)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `radacct` `ultimo_acct`
      ON (`ultimo_acct`.`username`=`t`.`login`) 
     AND (ultimo_acct.radacctid = (
         SELECT `radacctid` FROM
                  (SELECT radacctid
                     FROM `radacct` `fUzDDUDv` 
                    WHERE username = t.login
                  ) AS `fUzDDUDv` ORDER BY `radacctid` DESC LIMIT 1
                                  )
         )
(...)
```

**with this one:**

```
    (...)
INNER JOIN  
        (
         SELECT `ultimo_acct_INNER`.*
         FROM 
            `radacct` AS `ultimo_acct_INNER`
            INNER JOIN 
            (
             SELECT `fUzDDUDv`.`username` AS `maxID_username`, MAX(`radacctid`) AS `maxID_radacctid` 
             FROM  `radacct` `fUzDDUDv` 
             GROUP BY `fUzDDUDv`.`username`
            ) AS `radacct_MAX_ID` 
            ON `ultimo_acct_INNER`.`username`= `radacct_MAX_ID`.`maxID_username`
                AND `ultimo_acct_INNER`.`radacctid` = `radacct_MAX_ID`.`maxID_radacctid`
        ) AS `ultimo_acct`
        ON (`ultimo_acct`.`username`=`t`.`login`)
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following modification (for optimizing performance) ?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) 
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT `t_sub`.`id`
    FROM
    `radcliente` `t_sub`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `radacct` `ultimo_acct`
          ON (`ultimo_acct`.`username`=`t_sub`.`login`) 
         AND (ultimo_acct.radacctid = 
                      (SELECT `fUzDDUDv`.radacctid
                         FROM `radacct` `fUzDDUDv` 
                        WHERE `fUzDDUDv`.username = `t_sub`.login
                      ORDER BY `fUzDDUDv`.`radacctid` DESC LIMIT 1))
    WHERE (ultimo_acct.framedipaddress = '177.23.209.194')
 ) AS `t`
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_endereco_instalacao` `endereco_instalacao`
      ON (`endereco_instalacao`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_telefone` `telefones`
      ON (`telefones`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_email` `emails`
      ON (`emails`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `radmetodo_cobranca` `metodo_cobranca`
      ON (`metodo_cobranca`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`) AND (metodo_cobranca.arquivo = 'nao')
```

It preselects records joining first the clients table to the 'big' table 'radacct', selecting only the distinct set of 'right' client id-s and then joining this (relatively) small set to the rest of the tables in the topmost query

Comment: But there is not in default Yii. To take advantage of AR (all that my application is on) need to be more or less like the query I posted the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand now. I have no experience with Yii framework, so for know (taking into account your last comment) I can't think of something better than the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) 
 FROM `radcliente` `t`
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_endereco_instalacao` `endereco_instalacao`
      ON (`endereco_instalacao`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_telefone` `telefones`
      ON (`telefones`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `radcliente_email` `emails`
      ON (`emails`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `radmetodo_cobranca` `metodo_cobranca`
      ON (`metodo_cobranca`.`cliente_id`=`t`.`id`) AND (metodo_cobranca.arquivo = 'nao')
LEFT OUTER JOIN `radacct` `ultimo_acct`
          ON (`ultimo_acct`.`username`=`t`.`login`) 
         AND (ultimo_acct.radacctid = 
                      (SELECT `fUzDDUDv`.radacctid
                         FROM `radacct` `fUzDDUDv` 
                        WHERE `fUzDDUDv`.username = t.login
                      ORDER BY `fUzDDUDv`.`radacctid` DESC LIMIT 1))
WHERE (ultimo_acct.framedipaddress = '177.23.209.194')
```

I hope someone could help get more precise answer to your needs.

Comment: See my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26765729/unknown-column-in-where-clause-neste-subquery-to-improve-perfomance-of-order/26770085#comment42120014_26765729